# How to seek forward and replace selected characters with sed

Tags: regex, replace, sed

Can I use sed to replace selected characters, for example `H => X`, `1 => 2`, but first seek forward so that characters in first groups are not replaced.

Sample data:

```
"Hello World";"Number 1 is there";"tH1s-Has,1,HHunKnownData";
```

How it should be after `sed`:

```
"Hello World";"Number 1 is there";"tX2s-Xas,2,XXunKnownData";
```

What I have tried:

Nothing really, I would try but everything I know about sed expressions seems to be wrong.

Ok, I have tried to capture `([^;]+)` and "skip" (*get em back using ´\1\2´...*) first groups separated by `;`, this is working fine but then comes problem, if I use capturing I need to select whole group and if I don't use capturing I'll lose data.

Comment: please show us the expected output of the sample data

Comment: Where exactly should the substitution apply? What's the rule?

Comment: If you don't mind Perl, you can do this: `perl -pe '($s1,$s2,$s3)=split(/;/,$_); $s3 =~ s/H/X/g; $s3 =~ s/1/2/g; $_ = "$s1;$s2;$s3\n";'`

Comment: @LevLevitsky I want to skip some groups separated by `;` and make replacement for rest of groups, group count can differ but I'm ready to change expression as required. It would be nice if solution allows me to skip later groups too and do replace in middle but this is not iummediate requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with `sed`, but is kinda tedious. To do the translation if field number `$FIELD` you can use the following:

```
sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{'$((FIELD-1))'\}\)\([^;]*;\)/\1\n\3\n/;h;s/[^\n]*\n\([^\n]*\).*/\1/;y/H1/X2/;G;s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)/\2\1\4/'
```

Or, reducing the number of brackets with `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(([^;]*;){'$((FIELD-1))'})([^;]*;)/\1\n\3\n/;h;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*).*/\1/;y/H1/X2/;G;s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/\2\1\4/'
```

Example:

```
$ FIELD=3
$ echo '"Hello World";"Number 1 is there";"tH1s-Has,1,HHunKnownData";' | sed -r 's/(([^;]*;){'$((FIELD-1))'})([^;]*;)/\1\n\3\n/;h;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*).*/\1/;y/H1/X2/;G;s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/\2\1\4/'
"Hello World";"Number 1 is there";"tX2s-Xas,2,XXunKnownData";

$ FIELD=2
$ echo '"Hello World";"Number 1 is there";"tH1s-Has,1,HHunKnownData";' | sed -r 's/(([^;]*;){'$((FIELD-1))'})([^;]*;)/\1\n\3\n/;h;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*).*/\1/;y/H1/X2/;G;s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/\2\1\4/'
"Hello World";"Number 2 is there";"tH1s-Has,1,HHunKnownData";
```

There may be a simpler way that I didn't think of, though.

Comment: This is working and looks like good approach but I think that you should make it zero indexed as I believe that most programmers would start counting from zero :) Also saves few characters... Deserves +1

Comment: I think that another answer suits better for stuff like this. For me perl seems to be best so far http://stackoverflow.com/a/13489664/1338846 but I'm accepting this one because this is about `sed` and I asked about `sed`.

Comment: @Sampo I agree that `sed` does not provide the easiest way here, but I like to apply it to non-trivial problems :)

Answer (score 1):

If awk is ok for you:

```
awk -F";" '{gsub("H","X",$3);gsub("1","2",$3);}1' OFS=";" file
```

Using -F, the file is split with semi-colon as delimiter, and hence now the 3rd field($3) is of our interest. gsub function substitutes all occurences of H with X in the 3rd field, and again 1 to 2.

1 is to print every line.

Comment: @Sampo Updated with comments

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE]**

(I just realized that it could be shorter. Perl has an auto-split mode):

```perl
$F[2] =~ s/H/X/g; $F[2] =~ s/1/2/g; $_=join(";",@F)
```

Perl is not known for being particularly readable, but in this case I suspect the best you can get with `sed` might not be as clear as with Perl:

```bsh
echo '"Hello World";"Number 1 is there";"tH1s-Has,1,HHunKnownData";' | 
  perl -F';' -ape '$F[2] =~ s/H/X/g; $F[2] =~ s/1/2/g; $_=join(";",@F)'
```

Taking apart the Perl code:

```perl
# your groups are in @F, accessed as $F[$i]
$F[2] =~ s/H/X/g;      # Do whatever you want with your chosen (Nth) group.
$F[2] =~ s/1/2/g; 
$_ = join(";", @F)     # Put them back together.
```

`perl -pe` is like `sed`. (sort of.)

and `perl -F';' -ape` means use auto-splitting (`-a`) and set the field separator to `';'`. Then your groups are accessible via `$F[i]` - so it works slightly like `awk`, too.

So it would also work like `perl -F';' -ape '/*your code*/' < inputfile`

I know you asked for a `sed` solution - I often find myself switching to Perl (though I do still like `sed`) for one-liners.

Comment: Finally got some time to play with perl, this one turned  out to be good alternative. I don't know a lot about perl but it seemed that this can be extended pretty easily.

Comment: @Sampo you might find this interesting: http://lifecs.likai.org/2008/10/using-perl-like-awk-and-sed.html - as the author says, Perl is influenced both by `sed` and `awk` and as such can be used as a more powerful replacement for either. Definitely worth adding to your repertoire of one-liner tools!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F";" '{gsub("H","X",$3);gsub("1","2",$3);}1' Your_file
```

Comment: Thanks but this is exact duplicate, see [Guru's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13489245/1338846).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/H/X/2g;s/1/2/2g' file
```

This changes all but the first occurrence of `H` or `1` to `X` or `2` respectively

If it's by fields separated by `;`'s, use:

```
sed 's/H[^;]*;/&\n/;h;y/H/X/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//;s/1[^;]*;/&\n/;h;y/1/2/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

This can be mutated to cater for many values, so:

```
echo -e "H=X\n1=2"|
sed -r 's|(.*)=(.*)|s/\1[^;]*;/\&\\n/;h;y/\1/\2/;H;g;s/\\n.*\\n//|' |
sed -f - file
```